# when I open a ktor project, error Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.toString()" because the return value of "java.nio.file.Path.getFileName()" is null

Tags: build, ktor, build-error, r.java-file

when I open a ktor project in Intellij idea, I see this Error ===
Cannot invoke "java.nio.file.Path.toString()" because the return value of "java.nio.file.Path.getFileName()" is null

I create a kotlin ktor project using Ktor Project Generator
my project setting:
Build System : Gradil kotlin
Ktor version : 2.3.9
Engine       : Nitty

then I download this Project zip file and extract this file and Open this project using Intellij IDEA 2023.3.6 version.

[this is Project error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTzFh.png)

what is the problem of my project. how can I solve this.

Comment: What plugins did you select in the Ktor project generator to generate the project?